# Binary Tree, how to Count All Left and Right Child php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

[Table name classes I show you database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ7MW.jpg)

**I am try this code but output is 0**
Dear friend I have to count Left Child and Right Child of a Binary Tree My database structure is as under.

```
 function allcount($id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT parentsclass, childclassleft, childclassright FROM classes WHERE parentsclass = '".$id."'";
    $execsql = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
    $array = mysqli_fetch_array($execsql);  
    (array_count_values($array)); 
    $count = 0;  
    if(!empty($array['childclassleft']))
    {
        $count += allcount($array['childclassleft']) +1;
    }
    if(!empty($array['childclassright'])) 
    {
        $count += allcount($array['childclassright']) +1;
    }
    return $count; 
}

echo allcount();
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this in MySQL, but my friend wrote an article which I reblogged, which talks about binary search trees in PHP in some detail. It may possibly help you? But possibly not :-P https://delboy1978uk.wordpress.com/2018/02/06/binary-search-trees-in-php/

Comment: thanks brother but not solve

Comment: Why do you call `allcount` without a parameter? It should be pretty easy to debug this problem by outputting the SQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Used this code this code count left and right child node....

```
$memid="95000";   // your id

function getTotalLeg($memid,$leg){ 
      global $conn;
     $sql="select child_class from tree_class where parent_id='".$memid."' and position='".$leg."'";
      $res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
      global $total;
       $total=$total+mysqli_num_rows($res);
         if($row['child_class']!=''){
           getTotalLeg ($row['child_class'],'L');
           getTotalLeg ($row['child_class'],'R');
          } 
          return $total;      
        }      

     $total=0; 
    $left=getTotalLeg($memid,"L");    
    echo $total."</br>"; 
     $total=0;
    $right=getTotalLeg($memid,"R");  
    echo $total;
```